# How to get new site indexed and ranked by Alexa?

Tags: traffic, ranking, alexa

When I search my site on Alexa, it says "Alexa Traffic Rank: No Data".

I've read that to get a site indexed, you have to click "crawl my site" on the webmasters page. However there is no longer a link that says "crawl my site". So as of now, how does one get a site indexed by Alexa so that my traffic rank will display in the Alexa index?

Comment: Its been very long time and they say the same thing to me :(

Answer (score 11):

Install the Alexa spyware, I mean toolbar, and visit your website once a day.

Alexa is completely useless as a metric of any kind. I wouldn't spend any time worrying about it.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to http://www.alexa.com/siteowners/edit. You need to login to Alexa, you can also login with your facebook account. http://www.alexa.com/siteowners contains more tools for you that may help you to get your website crawled.

Answer (score 1):

Submit your site to alexa and after that alexa take 2-3 days only to indexed on alexa. Submit your website to alexa and wait for 2-3 days.