# Why would the Alexa traffic rank be low and Alexa have no information about visitors?

Tags: alexa, web-traffic

When a website is ranking below 200,000 on Alexa and the Audience Demographics graphic is all empty with no information about the visitors what could be the reason for this? Could it be crawlers traffic or fake visits?

Comment: Alexa is pure junk. Ignore it.

Comment: First you install the Alexa toolbar to join in along with the select few web developers, site administrators and marketing geeks who intensely care about SEO and Alexa. You then use it to browse your website and hope that some of the other Alexa SEO aficionados care enough to browse your website too. Then Alexa cobbles together some statistics that appear and you develop that feelgood for accomplishing the human equivalent of a NOP instruction. It's not a sampling of the general web population, relevance is questionable.

Comment: See also: [How to get new site indexed and ranked by Alexa?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17561/how-to-get-new-site-indexed-and-ranked-by-alexa)

Answer (score 1):

What it does mean is that the Alexa Rank being shown is either wrong or useless. The site must be fairly new with very low traffic. At low traffic, Alexa has doesn't have many data points (based on tool bar installations) and hence data tends to be off.

Ignore Alexa.