# How do I decrease alexa rank even Seo Activities are running?

Tags: seo, ranking, alexa

Currently I am Working on a website. In this site i do all activities regarding SEO. 15 days ago, its alexa rank was 140,260 and now its alexa rank is 195,200. Then what is the reason to increase alexa rank day by day?

Comment: See also: [How to get new site indexed and ranked by Alexa?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17561/how-to-get-new-site-indexed-and-ranked-by-alexa)

Comment: Also: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/why-do-alexa-rankings-for-a-site-fluctuate-by-millions-day-to-day/58606#58606 You can use the biases that makes Alexa junk to your advantage. There are a few big hints in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alexa’s Traffic Ranks are based on the traffic data provided by users in Alexa’s global data panel over a rolling 3 month period. You can not increase/ decrease their rank.

But please, don't concider Alexa rank as something important. Their data is very innacurate.

Comment: Thank you But actually Client wish that their blog's alexa range 40-60k in US and her blog is not responsive. Then which steps are required ?

Comment: @InteriordesignNYHomedecorNY get a new client? :o)

Comment: Then don't "learn" alexa.